# Python socket.connect strange behaviour

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I can't google it, and can't understand why this code works the way it works

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 28 2016, 18:08:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 33000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
>>> s.family
<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>
>>> 
>>>
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.family
<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 33000))
>>>
```

**Edited:**

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 28 2016, 18:08:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s2 = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 33000))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
>>> s.family
<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>
>>> s.type
<SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>
>>>
```

Looks like this is TCP socket =) I guess Python does some checks and drops incorrect values but does not provide any information about that trick.

Comment: Btw, this is true for python2 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket):

```
socket.socket([family[, type[, proto]]])
```

With `socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)` you use `SOCK_DGRAM` as family even though this is a type. This will cause strange problems like the one you have seen.

Comment: Yes! I've looked at stdlib socket.py source code, and seems like there are no guard/checks on the parameters. It's a bit confusing... Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment. Your guess is correct in some sense. Please look at edits

Comment: @NodariLipartiya: `SOCK_DGRAM`, `AF_INET` etc are just integers so it is hard to check. And `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP) is simply the default for type, i.e. for the argument you have omitted when giving only a single argument.